# windows batch copy command not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

windows batch copy cmd alone not working properly

```bat
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i IN ('date /t') DO SET DATE=%%k%%i%%j
REN \\server1\vinoth_new\vinoth\Test"*.txt*" SubroQuePrint.txt
copy \\server1\vinoth_new\vinoth\Test\SubroQuePrint.txt \\server1\vinoth_new
move /Y \\server1\vinoth_new\SubroQuePrint.txt 
\\server1\vinoth_new\Test\%DATE%SubroQuePrint.txt
```

Comment: I would start by joining the last two lines into one with a space separator.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Adopt @Compo's comment by separating your last two lines with a space instead of newline.

The end of your `copy` command is a bit weird.
Add a `\` at the end, alternatively a `\` followed by desired filename:

```
copy  \\server1\vinoth_new\vinoth\Test\SubroQuePrint.txt \\server1\vinoth_new\cp_SubroQuePrint.txt
```